# ion-button with left side icon and center text

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am designing below kind of UI. But icon and text both appearing to center. Any help to set icon on left and text on center of button as per attached image.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<ion-button expand="block">
    <ion-icon slot="start" src="assets/img/icons/vector.svg"></ion-icon>
    <span>
      Create New Alert
    </span>
</ion-button>
```

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-alignment
:)

Comment: @csaar ion-text-start and ion-text-center did not work with ion-button. any solution with ion-button.

Comment: I would probably use an ion-item instead of ion-button.

Comment: <ion-item lines="none" color="danger">
      <ion-icon name="close-circle" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="ion-text-center"> Create New Alert </ion-label>
    </ion-item> `add border radius on ion-item`